# javascript not working -> Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

With help I've made this function that posts the value of a selected option in my html form.

In this jsfiddle you can see the code and html.

anyone knows why this is not working? : http://jsfiddle.net/qqcAT/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catid").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $(".test").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly you'll see...

Comment: @elclanrs That's why I love Python.

Comment: @VisioN: It's all about preferences I guess. That's precisely why I dislike Python (and coffeescript), I like to have block statement terminators such as `}` to guide me thru the code. I like Ruby because of that, it has a very nice syntax as well as block terminators, think `end`...

Comment: @Zorayr Please **do not** change anything in the OP's code. Even if it is an obvious syntax mistake. I had to make a rollback.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, that's all about preferences. For me correct code styling makes a lot more sense, while Python makes me follow it: the code should be structured ideally, otherwise it won't work. I tend to see only advantage in here. At the same time I can support your idea about Ruby if and only if Ruby did not have that awful syntax, which brings me back to Perl time, when you need 10 more time to get the idea of the code after two seconds of pass.

Comment: Where's the non-working Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your Fiddle you will need something like this. I have not tested but should display the select text in division below it:

```
    $(function () {
$("#catid").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
      });
  $("div.test").text(str);
})
.trigger('change');
  });
```

Comment: Thx for the answers, can i do this also with just javascript, not jquery? Every time i include jquery, parts of the site not working.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `}` , indent your code next time.